# how to use dtm model/ wrappers dtm by mac?

Tags: python, macos, nlp, gensim

I want to use `wrappers.dtmmodel` by Mac. For Mac I need to use pre-compiled binaries for OS version unterladen https://github.com/magsilva/dtm/tree/master/bin
but wenn I download the `dtm-darwin64`, and try to run the code, the error shows:

> dtm_path must point to the binary file, not to a folder

What can I do to deal with this problem?

the code:

```py
from gensim.models.wrappers.dtmmodel import DtmModel

from gensim.corpora import Dictionary, bleicorpus

dtm_path = "/Users/123/Desktop/dtm-darwin64"

dtm_model = DtmModel(dtm_path, corpus, time_slice, num_topics=3, id2word=dictionary, initialize_lda=True)
```

And the error is :

> ValueError: dtm_path must point to the binary file, not to a folder

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To load a particular model you are supposed to provide a path to an individual file instead of a folder as you did with `dtm_path`.

Just pick one of the files in the folder, and provide the full path to a file.

Answer (score 0):

First download  pre-compiled binaries for your os  from :https://github.com/magsilva/dtm/tree/master/bin
Then put the direction in your code for example :
dtm_path = 'C:/Users/Windows T3N.6/Desktop/dtm-win64.exe'
please be sure that ‘.exe ’ is important for identifying this is a binary file